# Systemd not starting an app from wrapper

Tags: linux, shell, systemd, shell-scripting, ubuntu-16.04

I've created a simple wrapper for Elasticsearch and a systemd service file, and for some reason I am not able to start Elasticsearch from systemd, however I'm able to do so from the wrapper itself.

Here's my (very simple) wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=elasticsearch
PATH_TO_APP="/opt/$SERVICE_NAME/bin/$SERVICE_NAME"
PID_PATH_NAME="/var/run/$SERVICE_NAME/$SERVICE_NAME.pid"
SCRIPTNAME=elasticsearch-wrapper.sh
ES_USER=$SERVICE_NAME
ES_GROUP=$SERVICE_NAME
SUDO="sudo -u $SERVICE_NAME"

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
        mkdir $(dirname $PID_PATH_NAME) > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
            chown $ES_USER $(dirname $PID_PATH_NAME)
            $SUDO $PATH_TO_APP -d -p $PID_PATH_NAME
        echo "Return code: $?"
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ..."
            kill -15 $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill -15 $PID;
        sleep 1;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm -rf $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            mkdir $(dirname $PID_PATH_NAME) > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
            chown $ES_USER $(dirname $PID_PATH_NAME)
            $SUDO $PATH_TO_APP -d -p $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

And here's my `elasticsearch.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch Server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
#ExecStart=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d
ExecStart=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-wrapper.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-wrapper.sh stop
ExecReload=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-wrapper.sh restart
#ExecStop=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-stop.sh
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
User=root
StandardOutput=journal+console
```

This is the result of `systemd status elasticsearch` after attempting to run it:

```
● elasticsearch.service - ElasticSearch Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 systemd[1]: Started ElasticSearch Server.
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 elasticsearch-wrapper.sh[2866]: Starting elasticsearch ...
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 sudo[2872]:     root : unable to resolve host ip-10-96-13-64
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 elasticsearch-wrapper.sh[2866]: sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-96-13-64
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 sudo[2872]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=elasticsearch ; COMMAND=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 sudo[2872]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user elasticsearch by (uid=0)
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 sudo[2872]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user elasticsearch
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 elasticsearch-wrapper.sh[2866]: Return code: 0
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 elasticsearch-wrapper.sh[2866]: elasticsearch started ...
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 elasticsearch-wrapper.sh[2895]: elasticsearch is not running ...
```

I've put a debug statement that returns the "return code" when starting elasticsearch and as you can see in the `systemctl status` it is returning `0`. I've even tailed elasticsearch's logs immediately after executing `systemctl start elasticsearch` and nothing as in literally nothing in the logs; like it didn't even start elasticsearch.

I'm not sure why this is happening, so as a last resort I'm posting it here to see if anyone can help me out and point out what's going on here. To reiterate, starting/stopping/restarting elasticsearch from the wrapper directly works just fine with no problems, but with systemd, it doesn't work.

EDIT: The reason why I'm using the wrapper because, according to their [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/stopping-elasticsearch.html), you have to do `kill` the process. Also, I'd rather to have also the the `ExecReload` option.

EDIT2: To confirm that that there's no `stop` option in elasticsearch, here's the output of `elasticsearch --help`

```
USER# ./elasticsearch --help
starts elasticsearch

Option                Description                                              
------                -----------                                              
-E <KeyValuePair>     Configure a setting                                      
-V, --version         Prints elasticsearch version information and exits       
-d, --daemonize       Starts Elasticsearch in the background                   
-h, --help            show help                                                
-p, --pidfile <Path>  Creates a pid file in the specified path on start        
-q, --quiet           Turns off standard ouput/error streams logging in console
-s, --silent          show minimal output                                      
-v, --verbose         show verbose output
```

Comment: Why do you have a wrapper script at all? Everything necessary can be placed directly in the systemd unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so building on the information that iwaseatenbyagrue provided, Adding `PIDFile` worked only when I changed the `Type` from `simple` to `forking`, so now it works as expected!

Here's how my `elasticsearch.service` looks like now:

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch Server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
#ExecStart=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d
ExecStart=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-wrapper.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-wrapper.sh stop
ExecReload=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-wrapper.sh restart
#ExecStop=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-stop.sh
PIDFile=/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
User=root
StandardOutput=journal+console
```

Answer (score -1):

In most cases (and in the case of your unit file), systemd expects to be tracking a programme's PID directly.

Adding a wrapper means systemd sees the wrapper's PID, but cannot track ES's PID.

You can see this in your output:

```
Mar 23 17:38:30 ip-10-96-13-64 elasticsearch-wrapper.sh[2866]: Return code: 0
```

Your wrapper is exiting cleanly, and so systemd concludes nothing is running.

I would strongly recommend you move any necessary set-up functions to use systemd's `ExecStartPre`, and run ES directly from systemd.

If you absolutely must use a wrapper, then you should ensure ES writes a PID file, and provide systemd the path to it, using `PIDFile`.

However, I think you are better off having something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=ElasticSearch Server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=elasticsearch
Group=elasticsearch
ExecStartPre=-mkdir /opt/elasticsearch/data
ExecStart=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch OPTIONS
ExecStop=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch stop
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
StandardOutput=journal
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I'll try adding `PIDFile` to the systemd service file and report back.. And about the `chown`, the wrapper isn't finished and that's going to change for sure..

Comment: `PIDFile` doesn't seem to make it work.. Also the service file from your edited answer doesn't work because there's no `stop` option in elasticsearch's executable file, and also I'd like to have a `ExecReload` option too, hence why I created the wrapper.

Comment: Check my edited question.